# Creating a factory as a different class in Ruby with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I have some ActiveRecord superclass `Product` and a subclass `DiscountedProduct` that share the same table and I have some factories for the superclass that I want to use with the subclass.

```
Factory(:product).class #=> Product
```

What I am trying to find is a shorthand for:

```
DiscountedProduct.create(Factory.build(:product).attributes)
```

**NOTICE:**
I don't use `Factory.attributes_for` so that the needed associations get built.

- FactoryGirl **v2.3.2**
- Rails **3.0.4**

Comment: Have you tried `Factory(:discounted_product)`?

Comment: I have no such factory defined, only `:product`.

Comment: Define it then, and use `parent: product` while definition.

Answer (score 2):

Well, seems factory_girl supports quite well the inheritance.

You can define your factory either way :

- As a nested definition

  ```
  factory :product do
    name 'Product name'

    factory :discounted_product do
      discounted true
    end
  end
  ```
- or as  a linked definition

  ```
  factory :discounted_product :parent => :product do
    approved true
  end
  ```

Comment: No way to achieve it without the inheritance then?

Comment: Have you tried to overload the initialize method of the subclass? But I guess this won't call your parent factory definition, so the product fields may not be initialized.